# I have yearly data from 2011-2022. How do I calculate the difference between the minimum and maximum year?

Tags: r

I have data that lists diseases in a county along with the yearly rates from 2011-2022. I have created a subset of mock data below:

```
df <- data.frame(Year = as.integer(c(2020, 2021, 2022, 2020, 2021, 2022)),
                 Disease = c("Chlamydia", "Chlamydia", "Chlamydia", "Gonorrhea", "Gonorrhea", "Gonorrhea"),
                 Rate = as.numeric(c(30.75, 46.97, 98.75, 46.97, 29.34, 22.97)))
```

What I would like to do is group by the disease, take the maximum year's rate value (the max year would be 2022 in this example) and subtract it from the minimum year's rate (minimum year here would be 2020). The ideal output would be as listed below:

```
> df_dif
  Disease_dif Rate_Dif
1   Chlamydia       68
2   Gonorrhea      -24
```

These variable names and df names are totally malleable, all I need is the method to group by the disease and subtract the differences between the min and max year values. I am slightly new to coding, it would be greatly appreciated if you could explain your code. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

max_rates <- df |>
  filter(max(Year) == Year, .by = Disease)
  select(Disease, max = Rate)
min_rates <- df |>
  filter(min(Year) == Year, .by = Disease)
  select(Disease, min = Rate)

max_rates |> 
  left_join(min_rates) |> 
  mutate(Disease, Rate_Dif = max - min, .keep = "none")

    Disease Rate_Dif
1 Chlamydia       68
2 Gonorrhea      -24
```

Comment: Ahhhh very smart... Separate them into 2 different df's then rejoin them and mutate- didn't think about that. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Another option without splitting the data is to get corresponding `Rate` value of minimum and maximum `Year` and subtract them.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  summarise(Rate_Dif = Rate[match(max(Year), Year)] - 
                          Rate[match(min(Year), Year)], .by = Disease)

#    Disease Rate_Dif
#1 Chlamydia       68
#2 Gonorrhea      -24
```

We could also use `==` to compare the `Year` values however, using `match` is more safer since it will always return the first match ensuring that we always get only a single value.

Comment: Thanks for this, it is more convenient to not have to split up the data into multiple df's. Do you mind if I ask what match() does? I have never seen this function before and am curious as to what it does...

Comment: Sorry, I am a little confused as to what your code does... The way I am interpreting this is as follows...

Take the rate and subset it such that we take the rate of the highest year, and and subtract it by the rate at the most minimum year. I am a little confused as to why you put "Year" in the column subset, would you mind explaining?

Comment: `match` returns the index where the value matches. See for example `match(4, c(6, 2, 4))` so we get the index of `min` and `max` `Year` and then subtract the corresponding `Rate` values.

Answer (score 1):

Subsetting `x` for year `range` and calculating `diff` in `by`.

```
> by(df, ~Disease, 
+    \(x) data.frame(Disease_dif=x$Disease[[1]], 
+                    Rate_Dif=diff(with(x, Rate[Year %in% range(Year)])))) |> 
+   c(make.row.names=FALSE) |>  ## optional
+   do.call(what='rbind')
  Disease_dif Rate_Dif
1  Chlamydia        68
2  Gonorrhea       -24
```